# Shiny: renderDataTable throws error when renaming columns in data.frame

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that is creating a network visualisation. When the user clicks a node in the visualisation, a table is displayed detailing information about this node. All of this works beautifully as seen in the code below:

```
output$shiny_return <- renderDataTable({
    if(!is.null(input$current_node_id)) {
       kwic.file <- paste0(input$current_node_id, "_6.csv")
       kwic.data <- read.csv(file.path(config.analysis.basedir, config.kwic.basedir, kwic.file))

       output.table <- data.frame(getLetterUrlFromFile(kwic.data$file), kwic.data$left, kwic.data$keyword, kwic.data$right)
    }
}, escape = F)
```

However, the column names in the data table aren't what I want them to be in the output so I simply want to rename the columns in the output. I tried doing this by adding one line of code after the creation of the data.frame:

```
colnames(output.table) <- c("Letter", "Left Context", "Keyword", "Right Context")
```

Now the function throws an error:

```
Error: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)
```

I have tried renaming the columns using plyr as well and that doesn't seem to work. If I remove this one line, everything is fine (I just have ugly column names). Is there something I'm missing? Should I be renaming the column names in a different manner?

Comment: if `colnames(output.table) <- c(...` is the last expression, its result is returned instead of the data.frame. Add `output.table` or  `return(output.table)`  as the last expression of the code block to return the data.frame